# Is there a way to programmatically add search results to the search page?

Tags: magento2, php, search

I want to programmatically add some search results, and maybe do a bit more with the text that the user searches. Is this possible? Where would I inject my code?

edit: I found a somewhat similar question whose answer was to use the `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Collection` class, but the question was about magento 1 and I can't find the class anywhere in magento 2.

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2 is quite different from Magento 1 from a technical perspective.

The class you're looking for can be found here: 
`app/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection.php`